# Losing the value of child = window.load on parent page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dom-events

I am opening up a new child window on a button click event from parent window.

```
child = window.open('test.htm');
```

After opening a child window in a new tab or new page, when I redirect parent window from `home.aspx` to `search.aspx`, I am losing the value of child

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're redirecting to a new page.  The web is stateless.  Anything you want to share between pages requires you to pass it, either with a cookie, on the query string, through a form, etc

Comment: Thanks...Can you post sample code for that?? i am new to javascript and doesn't know much

Answer (score 0):

I am able to make this work.

Go to the fiddle, hit run, and then go to the 2nd link.

Click on the link to the favicon in the opened window (within 5 seconds) and you will see that it got the new url.

http://jsfiddle.net/lathan/c83Ek/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/draft

I think your problem is Cross-Domain Security.

Is your redirect changing from http to https (or vica versa) or is it changing the subdomain: www.site.com/home.aspx -> search.site.com/search.aspx?

Comment: no its the same domain...http://localhost/home.aspx to http://localhost/search.aspx